# DIsplay words in heat chart. Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here's the code for a heat map. I was wondering if I could change the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4 for letters such as A B C D each of them below each square.

```
'''
Most heatmap tutorials I found online use pyplot.pcolormesh with random sets of
data from Numpy; I just needed to plot x, y, z values stored in lists--without
all the Numpy mumbo jumbo. Here I have code to plot intensity on a 2D array, and
I only use Numpy where I need to (pcolormesh expects Numpy arrays as inputs).
'''
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#here's our data to plot, all normal Python lists
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4,5]
y = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4,5]

intensity = [
    [5, 10, 15, 20, 25,3],
    [30, 35, 40, 45, 50,23],
    [55, 60, 65, 70, 75,34],
    [80, 85, 90, 95, 100,24],
    [105, 110, 115, 120, 125,23],
    [105, 110, 115, 120, 125,23]
]

#setup the 2D grid with Numpy
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

#convert intensity (list of lists) to a numpy array for plotting
intensity = np.array(intensity)

#now just plug the data into pcolormesh, it's that easy!
plt.pcolormesh(x, y, intensity)
plt.colorbar() #need a colorbar to show the intensity scale
plt.show() #boom
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need the set_*ticklabels command. I changed your code after the setting of intensity as follows:

```
f, a = plt.subplots()
im = a.pcolormesh(x, y, intensity)
f.colorbar(im, ax = a) #need a colorbar to show the intensity scale
labels = [item.get_text() for item in a.get_xticklabels()]
labels = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
a.set_xticklabels(labels) #set xtick
a.set_yticklabels(labels) #set ytick
plt.show() #boom
```

The figure shows as follows:

[image: a busy cat]

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and most straight-forward way is the `pyplot.xticks()` method, which specifically targets the labels on the x-axis:

```
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

# add these lines here    
x_ticks = ['', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
plt.xticks(x, x_ticks)
```

note: the first label set as empty `''` to account for the origin:

[image]

Reference docs: http://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks